# webpack-dev-server - localhost not working 127.0.0.1 does work

Tags: webpack, localhost, webpack-dev-server, hosts

This one is a real head-scratcher. I've been using webpack-dev-server and localhost does **not** work on my computer, although it *does* on other people's computers, with the same setup.

I can access 127.0.0.1 on the same port (any open port is working the same), but not matter what I do localhost doesn't work.

I thought it was my webpack-dev-server config, but then I just tried gatsby which uses webpack-dev-server internally and had the same issue.

localhost for browsersync, docker, and node/express works fine. Here's my /etc/hosts file:

```
##
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting. Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

I'm on macOS sierra 10.12.6. Fresh install of gatsby is not working. But also on my own build I'm on webpack-dev-server 2.11.1.

Any ideas?

Comment: I still haven't figured this out myself. I am on macOS Sierra 10.13.3, webpack-dev-server 2.9.7 and it's doing the same for me (localhost - no, 127.0.0.1 works). What's really weird - this used to work, and if I change the port to something other than 8080, even localhost will work.

Comment: Interesting... No ports work for me unfortunately :(

Comment: Same here on Mojave. This happens to me in Chrome. But opening in Private tab works, opening with FF or Opera works. Testing with `curl` also works.